# Two TextView impliment count information after short title and long title(ellipsize end)

Tags: android

The first text is use to display title. the second is use to show this page list or recyclerview items size, my solution is use tow TextView, it work but I think is not good solution to deal with it. Any one show me another way to deal with it?

case 1:
title with short text, the count information just follow title

[image: title with short text, the count information just follow title]

case 2:
title with long text(ellipsize end), the count information title after ...
[image: title with long text(ellipsize end), the count information title after ...]

Comment: Code please, also so I am clear on what you want done, You want to get the number of letter in the string for the titles and place the number into the () right?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I update the question information! plz read again and change your aciton in this question? ths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:ellipsize="end"` to the TextView in your XML layout.

Comment: U forgot to add android:maxWidth  property in TextView !!!! I looking for another way to deal with this, have you any idea of it?

Comment: Maybe you can use two TextViews in a horizontal LinearLayout. Do not set their weights but set their width to `wrap_content`. No need to use `maxWidth` property. Just add the `maxLines` and `ellipsize` attribute to the first TextView.